# i have a trouble in arrays about base conversation

Tags: c

The purpose of this program is base conversion. It is intended to transform base 2 into base 10. When I execute the code, the program terminates without any error message.

What's wrong with my code?

```
main()    
{         
    int binary[25];    
    int counter_1;    
    int sum=0;    
    int counter_2=0;

    printf("enter the binary digits:");

    for(counter_1=0;binary[counter_1]==0 || binary[counter_1]==1;++counter_1)
    {
        scanf("%d",&binary[counter_1]);
    }
    for( ;counter_1>=0;counter_1--)
    {
        sum=sum+(pow(2,counter_2)*binary[counter_1]);
        counter_2=counter_2+1;
    }
    printf("your binary digits is equivalent to %d in decimal base.",sum);
}
```

Comment: change to `for(counter_1=0;scanf("%1d",&binary[counter_1]) == 1 && (binary[counter_1]==0 || binary[counter_1]==1);++counter_1)
  ;
    for(--counter_1 ;counter_1>=0;counter_1--)`

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing the contents of the array before they are initialized. Your program is subject to undefined behavior.

```
for(counter_1=0;binary[counter_1]==0 || binary[counter_1]==1;++counter_1)
                // ^^^ accessing uninitialized value
```

To read a binary number (1 or 0) to each of the elements of the array, you can use:

```
for(counter_1=0; counter_1 < 25; ++counter_1)
{
   scanf("%d", &binary[counter_1]);
   if ( binary[counter_1] != 0 && binary[counter_1] != 1 )
   {
      break;
   }
}
```